# how to get id from edittext created in linear layout by using long press event?

Tags: android-activity, android-linearlayout

```
LinearLayout cLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.col_linearlayout);
cLinearLayout.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener()
        {
              public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            if (v == cLinearLayout)  {
              System.out.println("CompID1::" + menu.size());
              System.out.println("Rowcount:"+ cLinearLayout.getChildCount());       
            }
            });
    }
```

In this code I am able to get only linear layout id. I want to get id of edit box that created inside that linear layout, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Make your EditText to final .**
so it can be accessible inside your linear.